# Disconnected received Connect: can't connect to amqp://guest@{rabbitTestHost:5672}:5672

Tags: scala, rabbitmq

I started RabbitMq on docker. This is the output of `docker ps`:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                                NAMES
93dcba1c9b74        rabbitmq:3          "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About a minute ago   Up 9 seconds        4369/tcp, 5671-5672/tcp, 25672/tcp   rabbitTestQueue
```

Then I used Scala code of [op-rabbit](https://github.com/SpinGo/op-rabbit) with the following configuration in application.conf:

```
-rabbit {
  topic-exchange-name = "rabbitTestQueue"
  channel-dispatcher = "op-rabbit.default-channel-dispatcher"
  default-channel-dispatcher {
    type = Dispatcher

    executor = "fork-join-executor"

    fork-join-executor {
      parallelism-min = 2
      parallelism-factor = 2.0
      parallelism-max = 4
    }
    throughput = 100
  }
  connection {
    virtual-host = "/"
    hosts = ["rabbitTestHost"]
    #username = "guest"
    #password = "guest"
    port = 5672
    ssl = false
    connection-timeout = 3s
  }
}
```

This is my code:

```
import akka.actor.{ActorSystem, Props}
import com.spingo.op_rabbit._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
import play.api.libs.json._

case class Query(query: String)

object MainApp extends App {
  import PlayJsonSupport._
  implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem("KaliumApp")
  implicit val dataFormat = Json.format[Query]

  val rabbitControl = actorSystem.actorOf(Props(new RabbitControl))
  implicit val recoveryStrategy = RecoveryStrategy.nack(false)
  import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

  val queryQueue = Queue("rabbitTestQueue", durable = false, autoDelete = true)
  val subscription = Subscription.run(rabbitControl) {
    import Directives._
    channel(qos=3) {
      consume(queryQueue) {
        body(as[Query]) { queryObj =>
          println(s"received ${queryObj.query}")
          ack
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I run my code, I get the following error:

```
akka://MainApp/user/$a/connection in Disconnected received Connect: can't connect to amqp://guest@{rabbitTestHost:5672}:5672//, retrying in 10 seconds
```

How can I solve this issue? Should I change some configuration in `application.conf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this message:

```
Connect: can't connect to amqp://guest@{rabbitTestHost:5672}:5672//
```

It looks as though the value of `["rabbitTestHost"]` is `rabbitTestHost:5672` when it should be just `rabbitTestHost`. Notice that `5672` is duplicated in the connect message.

Answer (score 3):

*amqp://guest@{rabbitTestHost:5672}:5672//*

5672 is not duplicated here its just the way op-rabbit print the log for the connection.